# Laravel/Eloquent returns JSON with slashes

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent, backslash

This is my database

[image]

I want to return content of "content" column with my API. In my controller I have

```
    public function index()
    {
        return Quiz::pluck('content');
    }
```

And this is what I get

[image]

There are those backslashes. I want to get JSON like this

[ { "question": "What color/colour is a polar bears skin?", "correct_answer": "Black", "answers": [ "White", "Pink", "Black", "Green" ], "selectedAnswer": null }, { "question": "What are rhinos horn made of?", "correct_answer": "Keratin", "answers": [ "Keratin", "Bone", "Ivory", "Skin" ], "selectedAnswer": null }, { "question": "What do you call a baby bat?", "correct_answer": "Pup", "answers": [ "Cub", "Chick", "Kid", "Pup" ], "selectedAnswer": null } ]

How can I do it with Eloquent/Laravel? And what if I don't want to return just "content" column but all columns?

Thank you

Comment: It's a JSON string, so quotes inside get escaped, that's why those backslashes are there. [Array & JSON Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) might help

Comment: `Quiz::find(1)` will return all columns for a quiz with id=1